# Passing arguments to PowerShell with "-Command" parameter using AutoHotKey and Windows Terminal

Tags: powershell, autohotkey, windows-terminal

My question pertains more toward PowerShell, but for completeness I am using AutoHotKey to run the PowerShell command.

I'm trying to pass some arguments to PowerShell with the "-Command" parameter, but running into issues if the arguments contain "special" characters.

For example, I have three folders:

```
c:\folder that works
c:\folder doesn't work
c:\[01] folder not working either
```

I am also testing both PowerShell 5.1 (built-in to Windows 10) and new PowerShell 7.0.1 (portable version) with Windows Terminal (wt.exe).  These are the commands I have tried using AutoHotKey:

```
Run, powershell.exe -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path '%Clipboard%'"
```

```
Run, wt.exe "c:\ps7\pwsh.exe" -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path '%Clipboard%'"
```

Either usage of PowerShell works with folders that don't contain special characters.

With a folder that has an apostrophe (seen as a single quote) in the name, such as `c:\folder doesn't work`, PowerShell 5.1 throws the following error:

```
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

PowerShell 7.0.1 doesn't even throw an error.  It doesn't show anything really.

With a folder that has square brackets "[]", both PowerShell 5.1 and 7.0.1 don't show anything either.  Not even an error.

I think I have an issue with escaping the characters or quoting it properly.

I would really appreciate any input on how I can get my code to work.

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention, I am using Windows Terminal (**wt.exe**) for PowerShell 7.0.1.

Comment: 1) Use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path` and 2) use (doubly escaped) double-quotes instead of single-quotes around the argument

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Using `-LiteralPath` and doubly escaped double-quotes, it works under PowerShell 5.1,  but not under PowerShell 7.0.1.

Comment: Does it throw the same error? (missing string terminator)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Forgot to mention I am using Windows Terminal in the command (`Run, wt.exe "c:\ps7\pwsh.exe" -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath ""%Clipboard%"""`).  Using PowerShell 7.0.1, it throws the error `Get-ChildItem: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'works'.` for `c:\folder that works`, and `Get-ChildItem: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'not'.` for`c:\[01] folder not working either`.  Nothing is displayed for `c:\folder doesn't work`.  **Without** `wt.exe`, PowerShell 7.0.1 works.

Comment: This is tough..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some experimentation, I have a partial answer to my own problem.  Both PowerShell 5.1 and 7.0.1, by themselves (**without the use of Windows Terminal**), work when using the following commands in AutoHotKey:

```
Run, powershell.exe -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command " Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath `"`"`"%Clipboard%`"`"`" "
```

```
Run, "c:\ps7\pwsh.exe" -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command " Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath `"`"`"%Clipboard%`"`"`" "
```

For some reason, I had to escape the quotes surrounding the AutoHotKey's `%Clipboard%`, three times using `` `" `` (backtick/grave and double quote)

But once I added Windows Terminal (wt.exe) to AutoHotKey's [Run](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) command, it would fail on all three folders in some way.  I think I'll create a separate question just for Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This works in cmd at least.  If the directory is empty, it won't show anything.

```
powershell dir -literal (get-clipboard)
pwsh -c dir -literal (get-clipboard)
```